# Unity Why can't the player turn towards the cursor in a 3d top-down game? (only Y-axis)Perspective Camera/LookAt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The game is made in 3D, and this is the main problem for creating the mechanics of directing the player to the cursor, since it works in 2D.

Here is the player code:

```
void Update(){
   RaycastHit hit;
   Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
   if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
      Vector3 pointToLook = hit.point;
      transform.LookAt(2 * transform.position - pointToLook);
   }
}
```

If that I use Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay and transform.LookAt, maybe they are not optimal for this task.

[Video with an example of the error](https://youtu.be/TfAqeflW2k0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that your `pointToLook` is below `transform.position`, as you are raycasting a plane, which is below. So when you use `lookAt` it directs your object a bit downwards.

Your vector `transform.position - pointToLook` will look a bit in the direction of the plane, so what you want is to take a part of this vector, that is in the same plane as your gameobject. Your gameobject lies horizontally with `transform.up` looking exactly at `Vector3.Up`

So let's make a projection.

```
Vector3 projection = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(transform.position - pointToLook, Vector3.up);
```

The next thing you want is to align your `transform.forward` (or maybe `right`, depends on your orientation) to that projection.

```
transform.forward = projection.normalized
```

And one more note: don't use `Camera.main` in `Update()`, as it uses `FindGameObjectWithTag()` which is slow. Cache reference to camera at `Start()`